# Printing first word after keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to get the first word after the specified keyword 'dataplane'

```
output = 'set interfaces dataplane dp0p1 vif 2129 description '*** WAN - Global ***''
```

I would like to get the word **dp0p1** that comes after dataplane

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wanted to possibly make more than one keyword, assuming `dataplane` should occur more than once, you could use `re.findall` here:

```
output = 'set interfaces dataplane dp0p1 vif 2129 description '
matches = re.findall('\\bdataplane (\S+)', output)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['dp0p1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no possibility for more than one keyword, assuming `dataplane` occurs once, you could use `next` here:

```
output = 'set interfaces dataplane dp0p1 vif 2129 description'

splitted = output.split()
print(next((y for x, y in zip(splitted, splitted[1:]) if x == 'dataplane'), ''))
```

This prints:

```
dp0p1
```